# WORDPRESS PLUGIN CREATION

Tags: wordpress-plugin-creation

My plugin do not show on left side in WordPress . Could you tell me why this happened?

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: We need technical details.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any technical details, I can only give you the following pointers.

First of all, when you create a plugin, it doesn't get a menu entry until you use the appropriate wordpress functions:

1. See [Wordpress Code Reference: add_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)
2. See [Wordpress Code Reference: add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)